# Object Oriented Javascript Error Object Is Not A Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, object, javascript-objects

I'm trying to create a simple marquee that simply changes in intervals. I am just trying to understand objects in Javascript. Currently, I am receiving the error, `object is not a function`.

```
var marquee = {

            domElement: jQuery( 'span' ),
            titles: [ 'First', 'Second', 'Third', 'Fourth' ],
            current: '',
            next: 0,

            _getCurrent: function(){

                this.current = this.domElement.text();

            },

            _setNext: function(){

                this.next = this.titles.indexOf( this.current ) + 1;

            },

            changeHeading: function(){

                this._getCurrent();
                this._setNext();
                this.domElement.text( this.titles[ this.next ] );

            }

        };

var marqueeInterval = setInterval( marquee.changeHeading, 700 );
```

Any help on why I can't get this to work would be greatly appreciated. I am new to Object Oriented Javascript, and am just trying to understand. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By passing the function reference of `changeHeading` to `setInterval`, you will lose context on each call. You either prevent that by adding an additional function like

```
setInterval(function() {
    marquee.changeHeading();
}, 700);
```

or invoke `Function.prototype.bind` like

```
var marqueeInterval = setInterval( marquee.changeHeading.bind( marquee ), 700 );
```

Comment: Brilliant! So basically, "this" no longer refers to marquee when being passed to setInterval? Am I understanding this correctly?

Answer (score 2):

Since you are passing `marquee.changeHeading` as a callback to the setInterval() method, when the method is invoked the execution context will not be `marquee` object

You can either use the [Function.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) as shown below

```
var marqueeInterval = setInterval( marquee.changeHeading.bind(marquee), 700 );
```

or a custom callback which will invoke the target method like

```
var marqueeInterval = setInterval( function(){
    marquee.changeHeading();
}, 700 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jQuery, simplest way to run your code is to replace your last line to line below

```
var marqueeInterval = window.setInterval($.proxy(marquee.changeHeading, marquee), 700);
```